# syntax error, unexpected 'else' (T_ELSE)

Tags: php, mysql, html

I was coding a basic Login system with a MySQL database, and I came across this problem. Any solution? This is also a live problem. If you go to OcelaRealms.com/proxy and try to login you get this error, "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'else' (T_ELSE) in C:\xampp\htdocs\proxy\login.php on line 40"

This is my code:

```
<?php

session_start();

$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

if ($username&&$password)
{

         $connect =  mysql_connect("192.168.1.19","root","xxx") or die ("Couldnt connect to MySQL database. Please contact Ocela at dylplum2002@gmail.com");
         mysql_select_db("proxy") or die ("Couldn't find database. Please contact Ocela at dylplum2002@gmail.com");

         $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username'");

         $numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);

         if($numrows !=0)

         {

         while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
         {

            $dbusername = $row['username'];
            $dbpassword = $row['password'];

         {
            if ($username==$dbusername&&$password==$dbpassword)
            {

               echo "Login succesful. <a href='/proxy/index.php'>Click here to enter the Premium Proxy.</a>";
               $_SESSION['username']=$dbusername;

            }
            else 
               echo "Incorrect password.";
         }

         else
            die "That login doesnt exist. To get an account please contact Dylan.";         


}
else
   die ("Please enter a username and password.");

?>
```

Comment: Post your code in the question.  indent 4 spaces for each code line or use the {} button at the top of the edit box

Comment: You're missing an `if` statement on line 27.

Answer (score 1):

You have added `{` inside your while and you also forgot to add `}` for your `if($numrows !=0)`

```
<?php

session_start();

$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

if ($username&&$password)
{

         $connect =  mysql_connect("192.168.1.19","root","xxx") or die ("Couldnt connect to MySQL database. Please contact Ocela at dylplum2002@gmail.com");
         mysql_select_db("proxy") or die ("Couldn't find database. Please contact Ocela at dylplum2002@gmail.com");

         $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username'");

         $numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);

         if($numrows !=0)

         {

             while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
             {

                $dbusername = $row['username'];
                $dbpassword = $row['password'];


                if ($username==$dbusername&&$password==$dbpassword)
                {

                   echo "Login succesful. <a href='/proxy/index.php'>Click here to enter the Premium Proxy.</a>";
                   $_SESSION['username']=$dbusername;

                }
                else
                   echo "Incorrect password.";
             }

        }
         else
            die "That login doesnt exist. To get an account please contact Dylan.";        


}
else
   die ("Please enter a username and password.");

?>
```